# Angular: Clear User Input on ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular, I am trying to find away to clear the user input inside a div when its visibility is toggled using ng-show. Ideally, when the conditions are met that cause the div to disappear, it should remove all of the user selected data from the div. Any help would be appreciated!

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="varA" ng-init="varA=false"> Item 1
  </div>
  <div ng-model="varB" ng-show="varA==false">
    <input type="checkbox"> Item 2
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'd be best served by writing a controller and manipulating your model there. Trying to do this in the markup, while perhaps technically possible, is not a good approach at all.

Comment: Technically you could place `ngModel` on your `div` element, but, I think, in your case, you should put it on your `input` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ng-reset-on`](https://github.com/waldirpereira/angular-reset-on) directive I've written. It can resets all fields based on an expression. You need to specify a `controller` and the field must have a `ng-model`.

```js
(function(){
    angular.module("app", ["ng-reset-on"]);
    angular.module("app").controller("AppCtrl", function() {}); 
})();
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/waldirpereira/angular-reset-on/master/dist/angular-reset-on.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="varA" ng-init="varA=false"> Item 1
    </div>
    <div ng-show="varA==false">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="varB" ng-reset-on="varA==true"> Item 2
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Super useful! Waldir, thank you very much for sharing! In my case, I had to change the requirement to be optional: require: '?ngModel'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngChange` on your checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkboxChanged()" ng-model="varA" ng-init="varA=false">
```

Then in your controller implement the `checkboxChanged` function:

```
$scope.checkboxChanged = function() {
   $scope.varB = '';
};
```

By the way, `ngModel` is meant only for `input`, `select`, and `textarea` only. Do not use `ngModel` with a `div`.